# Why do I see a Bitcoin address prefix starting with 4?

Tags: transactions, counterparty

I have an old Bitcoin (Counterparty) wallet that I am importing past transactions. I found a Tx that has a missing output address on one API, but it shows on another. I cannot find any documentation on what the Bitcoin address prefixed with '4' means. Is this valid or just a place holder?

Tx Hash: 5288973c6e2a323a2fbc95b84fbfd18b4ed2f75895c8295db03c653ea58c70d6

Blockcypher is showing the '4' (4PTehVhW6qTNhn88DK3JPBMkXfB2wR4juB)
https://api.blockcypher.com/v1/btc/main/txs/5288973c6e2a323a2fbc95b84fbfd18b4ed2f75895c8295db03c653ea58c70d6

Original API call is through Blockchain.Info
https://www.blockchain.com/btc/tx/5288973c6e2a323a2fbc95b84fbfd18b4ed2f75895c8295db03c653ea58c70d6

Blockchain just says "Unable to decode output address".

This is a counterparty transaction so I am thinking it may have something to do with that. Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

I see it as multisig script on [OXT](https://oxt.me)

[image: oxt]

[Blockchair](https://blockchair.com) shows it as multisig address: `m-99d8dc4aa2b7f5b105fe442f651d73e6`

[image: blockchair]

[blockstream.info](https://blockstream.info) shows UNKNOWN

[image: blockstream-info]

Comment: Interesting. Looks like it might be a multisig counterparty wallet for the old SJCX token. Maybe a change address. Mostly find it odd that it can't be translated by most software. Not really a big deal on my end, just really curious. Thanks for the info.

Comment: Yes it appears that it was a multisig address but format as specified by counterparty so most of the block explorers unable to read it. I have never used counterparty but these two links had some information about multisig address format: https://counterparty.io/docs/multisig_counterwallet/ https://counterparty.io/docs/multisig_counterparty-server/

Answer (score 1):

These are bare multisig scripts, there is no address format for such type of output. So explorers basically came up with confusing (and constantly differents, as there is no *right* one) placeholders.